# Filling values under child through element tree

Tags: python

I have an xml file and another text file and i had written script to parse the text file and get a dictionary with keys and values ,Now i have to go inside the xml file and fill the values for child of child testgroup,the values include test case_title ,inddent etc,

And also based on the length of aa in the script i need to create child under test group,i have minimum exposure in elementtree,Any recomendation would be highly helpful.

```
 xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <testmodule title="hello" version="version 2">
       <description> 'world' </description>

       <engineer>
           <info>
               <name>Test </name>
               <description> 'test' </description>
           </info>
       </engineer>

       <preparation>
           <initialize title="Set">
           </initialize>
       </preparation>
     <variants>
        <variant name="A">Test  </variant>
        <variant name="B">test</variant>
        <variant name="C">Test  test</variant>
    </variants>

       <testgroup title="Testing" ident="Testing" >

                    <testcase title="Check" ident= "3_1" name="Number" variants="A">
                        <param name="Testcase" type="string">Checking of Correct SW and Part identifiers </param>
                        <param name="TestcaseRequirements" type="string"></param>
                        <param name="Test" type="string">TS_Automation=Manual;TS_Method=Bench_Test;TS_Priority=1;TS_Tested_By=rjrjjn;TS_Written_By=SUN;TS_Review_done=No;TS_Regression=No;</param>
                    </testcase> 
    """



ee=''
with open('C:\\Users\\rjrn8w\\Desktop\\Test.txt', "r") as f:
    for i in f:
        ee+=i
import re
aa=re.findall(r'<TC_HEADER_START>([\s\S]*)</TC_HEADER_END>',ee)

for j in aa:

    k=j.strip()
    new_dict={}
    ak=dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)=(.*)', j.strip()))
    print ak
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse('C:\\Users\\rjrn8w\\Documents\\My Received Files\\new.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
        if  child.tag=='testgroup':
            for element in child:
                for elem in element:
                    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
                    print elem.tag


 ak={'TS_Regression': 'No', 'ident': '1 ', 'TestcaseRequirements': '36978', 'name': '"T01">', 'title': '"DHCP " ', 'TS_Review_done': 'Yes;', 'TestcaseTestType': 'Test', 'TS_Priority': '1;', 'TS_Tested_By': 'qz9ghv;', 'TS_Techniques': 'Full Testing;', 'variants': '"A C" ', 'StakeholderRequirements': '1236\t\t\t\t', 'TS_Implemented': 'Yes;', 'TS_Automation': 'Automated;', 'TestcaseDescription': ' This test verifies DHCP discovery is halted after tester is connected'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read python documentation, it have content of how to create Element, add attribute , add values and how to append the new element to existed element as a child.

```
child=xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra) 
existedelement.append(child)
```